# Correct behavior for std::setprecision(0) in GCC vs VS2013

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-2013

Depending on which compiler I use, I get a different out put for this function at n=0.

```
std::string ToStrWPrec(double a_value, const int n)
{
    std::ostringstream out; 
    out << std::setprecision(n) << a_value; 
    return out.str();
}
```

(GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) returns 1 for ToStrWPrec(1.2345678,0). VS2013 returns 1.2346 for same code.

my question are:

1. What is the correct/standard behavior for setprecision?
2. what would be good alternative to using setprecision?

---

here is the updated code based on comment below

```
std::string ToStrWPrec(double a_value, const int n)
{
    std::ostringstream out; 
    out << std::setprecision(n) << std::fixed<< a_value; 
    return out.str();
}
```

Comment: You must [use std::fixed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/) to get a reproducible result.  MSVC++ assumes std::scientific when none is specified.

Comment: This actually solved my problem and provided consistent result between GCC and VS2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to 22.4.2.2.2 [facet.num.put.virtuals] paragraph 5, Stage 1, this is said about the precision:

> For conversion from a floating-point type, if `floatfield != (ios_base::fixed | ios_base::scientific), str.precision()` is specified as precision in the conversion specification. Otherwise, no precision is specified.

The same paragraph specifies elsewhere that the format specifier defining the result is `%g`.

The default value for the `floatfield` is nothing set according to 27.5.5.2 [basic.ios.cons] paragraph 3, Table 128:

> `flags()` `skipws | dec`

Thus, it boils down how a format string of `"%.0g"` formats the value. The C standard in 7.21.6.1 paragraph 8 states this:

> Let *P* equal the precision if nonzero, 6 if the precision is omitted, or 1 if the precision is zero.

It seems, the correct result is `1`.